# Google Chrome fails to update

Tags: google-play-store, updates, chrome-for-android

I'm on Android 10.
When I open google chrome its menu is replaced with a red icon.
On clicking it there's a red menu item "Update Google Chrome" or so.
On invoking that action I get to a new screen (I think from google play store) which says "Try again". On the bottom it suggests to play "Hot Balloon" in the meanwhile.
I tried this for weeks and it was always the same.
I tried rebooting but it didn't help.
I tried updating from within the Play Store app. There was an Update button but when I clicked it it just said "something went wrong".
I checked if there's enough storage. Both internal storage and SD card have >3 GB left.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution here:
https://customeruseinfo.com/solved-google-chrome-and-system-webview-isnt-getting-up-to-date/ > Clear Google Play Store Cache and Storage

Settings > Apps and Notifications > Google Play Store > Storage & Cache > Clear storage
Then confirm and try updating again -> works